# Find all pattern indexes in string in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, indexing

How can I find all indexes of a pattern in a string using c#?

For example I want to find all `##` pattern indexes in a string like this `45##78$$#56$$JK01UU`

Comment: How do you define a "pattern"?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you tried Regular Expressions?

Comment: Could you show some input strings and intended output ?

Comment: input pattern is ##
string is 45##78$$#56$$JK01UU

Comment: string SearchPattern = "##";
string Str = "45##78$$#56$$JK01UU";

Comment: @petre: SearchPattern and Str are input strings, what do you want to output as the result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 string pattern = "##";
 string sentence = "45##78$$#56$$J##K01UU";
 IList<int> indeces = new List<int>();
 foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(sentence, pattern))
 {
      indeces.Add(match.Index);
 }
```

indeces will have 2, 14

Comment: or in 1 line: var indexes = Regex.Matches(_msg, pattern).Select(x => x.Index).ToList();

Answer (score 3):

Edited the code to make it a cleaner function.

```
public IEnumerable<int> FindAllIndexes(string str, string pattern)
{
    int prevIndex = -pattern.Length; // so we start at index 0
    int index;
    while((index = str.IndexOf(pattern, prevIndex + pattern.Length)) != -1)
    {
        prevIndex = index;
        yield return index;
    }
}

string str = "45##78$$#56$$JK01UU";
string pattern = "##";

var indexes = FindAllIndexes(str, pattern);
```

Comment: I guess this must be faster than the answers that use regex. Would be nice to have some profiling results.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the indices of a pattern in a string by using a regex search like this.

```
string input = "45##78$$#56$$JK01UU", pattern = Regex.Escape("##");
Regex rx = new Regex(pattern);
var indices = new List<int>();
var matches = rx.Matches(s);
for (int i=0 ; i<matches.Length ; i++)
{
    indices.Add(matches[i].Index);
}
```

Comment: You probably need to run `Regex.Escape()` on the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Another one that tries to be efficient:

```
public IEnumerable<int> FindPatternIndexes(string input, string search)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(input);

    for (var i = 0; search.Length <= sb.Length; i++)
    {
        if (sb.ToString().StartsWith(search)) yield return i;
        sb.Remove(0,1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested. Worked. But somewhat dumb.

```
string foo = "45##78$$#56$$JK01UU";
char[] fooChar = foo.ToCharArray();

int i = 0;
bool register = false;

foreach (char fc in fooChar)
{
    if (fc == '#' && register == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Index: " + (i-1));
    }
    else if (fc == '#')
    {
        register = true;
    }
    else
    {
        register = false;
    }
    i++;
}
```