# Find all indexes for a specified string within a string in C#

Tags: c#, regex

Hi I am trying to use the solution from

[Find all pattern indexes in string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546302/find-all-pattern-indexes-in-string-in-c-sharp)

However, it doesn't work in my situation

```
string sentence = "A || ((B && C) || E && F ) && D || G";
string pattern = "(";
IList<int> indeces = new List<int>();
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(sentence, pattern))
{
  indeces.Add(match.Index);
}
```

It produces error , "parsing "(" - Not enough )'s".

I am not sure what I have done wrong here.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Balan Sinniah

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am not sure what I have done wrong here.

You've forgotten that `(` has a special meaning within regular expressions. If you use

```
string pattern = @"\(";
```

it should work, I believe. Alternatively, just keep using `string.IndexOf` given that you're not really using the pattern-matching of regular expressions.

If you *are* going to use regular expressions, I'd personally create a `Regex` object rather than using the static method:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(Regex.Escape("("));
foreach (Match match in pattern.Matches(sentence))
...
```

That way there's rather less scope for confusion around which argument is the input text and which is the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Using Regexs on this is overkill - IndexOf is enough.

```
string sentence = "A || ((B && C) || E && F ) && D || G";
string pattern = "(";
IList<int> indeces = new List<int>();
int index = -1;
while (-1 != (index = sentence.IndexOf('(', index+1)))
{
  indeces.Add(index);
}
```

or, in your case, you need to escape the `(`, as it is special character for regex, so the pattern would be `"\\("`

EDIT: fix, thanks Kobi

Comment: Op wants *all* the indices though ... you'd have to make multiple calls to *IndexOf*, wouldn't you?

Comment: @dbaseman, yeah, definitely. But I'm pretty sure it would be faster than using Regex at all.

Comment: You may want `while (-1 != (index = sentence.IndexOf('(', index + 1)))` if you want your program to ever stop. Until then, regex is definitely faster `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the `(`.

In other words:

```
string pattern = "\\(";
```

Comment: Or you can also at a at before the string so you dont have to escape the backslash `@"\("`