# How to get the indexes of list that contains a string

Tags: c#, winforms, list

I have a `List<string>` and i check if it contains a string:

```
if(list.Contains(tbItem.Text))
```

and if it's true I do this:

```
int idx = list.IndexOf(tbItem.Text)
```

But what if I have for example 2 same strings? I want to get all the indexes that have this string and then use foreach to loop through it. How I can do that?

Comment: what is list? is it List<T>?

Comment: @kashif yes List<string>

Comment: @loclip write complete coding that you have

Comment: Some very similar questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641326/finding-all-positions-of-a-substring-in-a-large-string-in-c-sharp
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546302/find-all-pattern-indexes-in-string-in-c-sharp
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991568/find-all-indexes-for-a-specified-string-within-a-string-in-c-sharp?lq=1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming *list* is a `List<string>`:

```
IEnumerable<int> allIndices = list.Select((s, i) => new { Str = s, Index = i })
    .Where(x => x.Str == tbItem.Text)
    .Select(x => x.Index);

foreach(int matchingIndex in allIndices)
{
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks that working great.. I assuming other answers working as well so thank you all guys..

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
List<int> matchingIndexes = new List<int>();
for(int i=0; i<list.Count; i++)
{
    if (item == tbItem.Text)
        matchingIndexes.Add(i);
}

//Now iterate over the matches
foreach(int index in matchingIndexes)
{
    list[index] = "newString";
}
```

or get the indexes using linq

```
int[] matchingIndexes = (from current in list.Select((value, index) => new { value, index }) where current.value == tbItem.Text select current.index).ToArray();
```